# How do I remove words with less than 3 characters from a cell?

Tags: regex, excel, vba, text-mining

I'm trying to create a word cloud in Tableau but I need to prep the data in Excel first. I already removed all characters that weren't alphanumeric. But now I want to remove the words like not, it, or is.

I honestly just want to remove all the words with less than 3 characters. I tried the following two pieces of code using VBA.

```
Sub removeSmallWords()
ScreenUpdating = False

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A10")

Dim oReg As Object
Set oReg = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

For Each cell In rng
    With oReg
        .Pattern = "(\s|^)(\w{1,2})(\s|$)"
        .Global = True
        cell.Value = .Replace(cell.Value, " ")
    End With
    cell.Value = Trim(cell.Value)
Next cell

Set oReg = Nothing
ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But this created an error that said Active X Can't create the component.

The second thing I tried was this:

```
Sub removeSmallWords()
ScreenUpdating = False

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A1:A10")

Dim stringArray() As String
Dim newString As String

For Each cell In rng
    newString = ""
    stringArray = Split(cell.Text)

    For i = 0 To UBound(stringArray)
        If Len(stringArray(i)) > 3 Then
            newString = newString & " " & stringArray(i)
        End If
    Next i

    cell.Value = Trim(newString)
Next cell

ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This just doesn't do anything. I select a cell with only plain text. I go to "Run Macro" and I select it and hit run. Nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The second macro works on the range **A1** through **A10**, not a cell you have `Selected`.

Also replace:

```
    If Len(stringArray(i)) > 3 Then
```

with:

```
    If Len(stringArray(i)) > 2 Then
```

To retain words with 3 characters.

Comment: How do I make the second one work on the cells I selected?